# How did English come to use a variation of the Polish spelling for Czechoslovakia?

Tags: etymology, orthography, toponyms

In English, and a few languages influenced by English (e.g. Malay, Samoan, Yoruba), the name of the former European country is spelled "Czechoslovakia".

That isn't how it is spelled in other languages though, not even in Czech ("československo").

But it *is* close to the Polish spelling ("**cz**e**ch**osłowacja"), where Polish "cz" is similar to the English "ch" sound, and Polish "ch" is similar to the German or Scottish "ch".

Did the "**cz**e**ch**" English spelling come from Poland, and if so how and why?

Comment: Yes, apparently, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_the_Czech_Republic)

Comment: Before there was Czechoslovakia, there was the Czech language and the Slovak language.Putting them together gives the hybrid Polish/French spelling. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Czech+language%2CSlovak+language%2Cwent+to+Czechoslovakia&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CCzech%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSlovak%20language%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwent%20to%20Czechoslovakia%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: English tends to take foreign names and 1) Retain the foreign spelling and pronounce it like English, 2) Retain the pronunciation and respell as if it were an English word, or 3) Mispronounce the word to sound English and then spell it that way (e.g. Florence instead of Firenze, Ceylon instead of Sri Lanka). But in this case English took the Polish spelling of a Czech word, which seems extremely unusual, especially since no other language uses a similar spelling, and there isn't a close connection with Poland.  I'm wondering how and why this happened.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possible Polish (or Latin) connection, but this was made by the Czechs themselves:

OED:

> **Origin**: Of multiple origins. Partly a borrowing from German. Partly a borrowing from Czech. Etymons: German Tscheche; Czech Čech.

NB Č = Cz = [Ch]

> **Etymology**: < (i) German Tscheche (17th cent. or earlier), and (ii) its etymon Czech Čech, self-designation (14th cent. in Old Czech; plural Češi, (inanimate) Čechy); further etymology unknown.
>
> It is uncertain whether the following earlier instance should be interpreted as showing the post-classical Latin or English word:
>
> 1610   P. Holland tr. W. Camden Brit. i. 23   *They that nominated themselves after their owne language Teutsch, Numidians and Hellenes, by the Romanes were named Germans, Mauri and Grecians. Even so in these daies..they which in their owne Idiome are called Muselmans, Magier, Czecchi and Besermans [L. Muselmanni, Magier, Czechi, Besermanni], are by all nations in Europe named Turkes, Hungarians, Bohemians, and Tartarians.*
>
> With use as adjective compare an isolated earlier use as adjective of Chechi < either Czech Čechy (plural noun; also used as a name of the country: see Czechian n.) or perhaps post-classical Latin Czechi (plural noun; see below):
>
> 1759   Mod. Part Universal Hist. XII. xv. vii. 127   Being joined by the Chechi (or Bohemian), Pole, Latin, and Bulgarian, Valak Ogli's auxiliaries, he leads them into the Musulmȃn dominions.
>
> With the β. forms compare Old Czech *Czech*, the usual form in the 15th cent. This was later replaced by **Čech** in Czech orthography, but the digraph cz was often retained in **post-classical Latin** Czechi (alongside Zechi; both plural, second half of the 16th cent. or earlier), *perhaps partly under the influence of Polish Czech (plural Czesi)*.

Comment: The question was not about the origin of the name itself, but specifically about its **spelling**.

Comment: @jsw29 See *This was later replaced by Čech in Czech orthography, but the digraph cz was often retained in post-classical Latin Czechi* and *NB Č = Cz = [Ch]* and *they which in their owne Idiome are called Muselmans, Magier, **Czecchi** and Besermans* above.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on [Czech orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_orthography) says that "cz" was replaced in the 14th or 15th century by a dotted C, and then in the 16th century by the hacek we know today. So it's not clear how the old Czech spelling could have directly influenced English, when the word Czech didn't come into wide use till the 19th century. It's possible as the quote says that the Latin Czechi played a role, although even then you have an alternative Latin spelling Zechi, and the German and French spellings were at one time widely used according to the OED.

Comment: @StuartF The Czech- spelling was widely used by Czechs themselves when writing in Latin, when not using the word Bohemia and  derivatives. You can search, e.g., for "Czechia" in old books https://www.google.com/search?q=czechia&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1750&tbm=bks